# c# преобразование object в указанный тип

Tags: c#, преобразование-типов, приведение-типов

Предположим есть 2 класса MyClass1 и MyClass2, которые в целом различны, но содержат одинаковые поля (например field1 и field2).

Хочу такую функцию которая принимала бы в себя:

object, который на самом деле является MyClass1 или MyClass2

и string, в котором бы было наименование типа (MyClass1 или MyClass2).

Внутри:
полученный object интерпретируется нужным образом и происходят необходимые преобразования над общими по названию полями (field1 и field2) и возвращается обратно преобразованный object. Дублировать код для обоих возможных вариантов не хотел поэтому спрашиваю..

что то типа:

```
public object MyFunc(object obj, string typeName)
{
    Type realType;
    if (typeName == "MyClass1")
    {
        realType = typeof(MyClass1);
    }
    else if (typeName == "MyClass2")
    {
        realType = typeof(MyClass2);
    }

    (realType)obj.field1 = 123;
    (realType)obj.field2 = 456;
    return obj;
}
```

но так конечно не работает. Как быть? Может какой то другой подход использовать?
полей для редактирования может быть 20+потребность в том чтобы блок кода с назначением полей был универсален для обоих классов

Comment: в чем смысл передавать `typeName` - если поля одинаковые и список полей, которые надо изменить известен заранее?

Comment: чтобы преобразовать в нужный тип.. если можно без него покажите плз как.

Comment: рефлексией выбираешь нужные поля [GetField](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getfield?view=net-6.0) и ставишь им выбранные значения [SetValue](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.fieldinfo.setvalue?view=net-6.0#system-reflection-fieldinfo-setvalue(system-object-system-object-system-reflection-bindingflags-system-reflection-binder-system-globalization-cultureinfo))

Comment: рефлексия, `dynamic`, сделай для классов общий интерфейс/общий базовый класс

Comment: Сформулируйте задачу чуть иначе. Я правда пытаюсь понять, что вы хотите сделать, но никак не удаётся. Что я сейчас понял: вы хотите передать в метод экземпляр класса и вернуть оттуда свойство по нужному имени?

Comment: @Frehzy, нет, судя по описанию, у автора есть два класса, у которых некоторые поля совпадают по имени. И в функции он хочет установить эти поля. Не зная объект какого класса ему придет

Comment: Если у классов есть общие поля, то их можно вынести в базовый класс и унаследовать MyClass1 и MyClass2 от него. Если изменять MyClass1 и MyClass2 нельзя, то можно сделать два метода (для MyClass1 и для MyClass2) - возможно, код расчета 123 и 456 можно вынести и переиспользовать в обоих методах

Comment: Все же создавать базовый класс для двух совершенно разных классов (`которые в целом различны`) с точки зрения архитектуры не очень хорошо

Comment: @Grundy Подправил код. Я не смог понять, какое конкретно значение нужно вставить. Сама задача крайне странная

Comment: @Pekor так они не "совершенно разные" - у них есть одинаковые поля, которые используются в общей логике. И именно эта общая часть должна быть в базовом классе - все остальные "в целом различные" поля при этом остаются в самих классах

Comment: @Regent тогда вообще не вижу проблемы, создаешь базовый класс а потом через `is` или `as` кастуешь к нужному классу

Comment: @Regent, не всегда можно сделать общий интерфейс ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Pekor а зачем кастовать при использовании базового класса? `public BaseClass MyFunc(BaseClass obj) { obj.field1 = 123; obj.field2 = 456; return obj; }` и всё

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил через наследование от родительского класса, а в функции перед изменением завожу экземпляр родительского класса, запихиваю в него приведенный объект и в нем меняю нужные поля